# Querying NEST 2.0.0-rc1 Aggregation Buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Previously in NEST (for Elasticsearch 1.x), after an aggregation query, I had some code that went through and grouped up aggregations by going through all the buckets, similar to this:

```
var r = (from SingleBucket items1 in result.Aggregation.Values
select (Bucket) agg1
into items1Aggs
from col1 in items1Aggs.Items.Cast<KeyItem>()
....
select new x {}).ToList();
```

But it seems that now the `SingleBucket` has to be `SingleBucketAggregate`, but the `Bucket`class used before is now an internal `BucketAggregateData` class that is no long accessible. Is there any way around this?

Aggregation query being used:

```
var result = _client.Search<MetaStoreEntry>(s => s
  .Aggregations(a => a
    .Filter("fullGroupBy", k => fad
      .Aggregations(e => e
        .Terms("col1", t => t
          .Field(f => f.col1)
            .Aggregations(b => b
            .Terms("col2", u => u
              .Field(f => f.col2)
            ...
            ).Size(int.MaxValue).CollectMode(TermsAggregationCollectMode.DepthFirst)
          ) ...
);
```

Comment: `BucketAggregateData` has been renamed to `BucketAggregate` and made public again - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/commit/a1753147134fffa20a17d53c0c8b3c1d3480ae26. This will be in the GA release (_hopefully today_)